# Google Maps API isn't loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-api

On my website: http://www.ilovefooddreams.com/eligibility The maps were working completely fine but now all of the sudden it says:

**

### Oops! Something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.

**

Does anyone know what is wrong? Here is my code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block header_class %}header-expanded slidepanel top
{% endblock %}
{% block header_content %}
  {{ super() }}

<div style="image-align:left;">
<h2 class="heading h-section" data-barley="index_heading"style="color:black" data-barley-editor="simple">You are eligible for delivery at any address within this circle.</h2>
 </div>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDV9O4nd02xCwyy-AeAmFJ_dR3SKh5GKAE&callback=initMap">
</script>

<script>

var amsterdam=new google.maps.LatLng(34.0789742,-118.361875);
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:amsterdam,
  zoom:13,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
  center:amsterdam,
  radius:3000,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:2,
  fillColor:"#0000FF",
  fillOpacity:0.4
  });

myCity.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:1030px;height:380px;"></div>


</body>
</html>



   {% endblock %}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: seems the key you are currently using does not exist: js?key=AIzaSyDyUno31jMgeeK3TDsrlcBmKsfn4hchg&callback=initMap:Google Maps API error: InvalidKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key-map-error

Comment: It exists.... Look: http://imgur.com/a/BIBcN This is the key: AIzaSyDy_Uno31jMgeeK3TDsrlcBmKsfn4hc-hg @kaskader

Comment: @kaskader Do you know whats happening?

Comment: you were missing a dash and the underscores in the one on your page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have an API key.

Right here in your code :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

something is missing. It should look like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**YOUR_API_KEY**&callback=initMap"></script>
```

You will get your API key following this documentation under the point **Get API Key:**
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=de

or
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=en (in English)

Then add this in the link above and your all set!

Comment: I get an error saying InitMap is not a function. Why is this?

Comment: What should I do? @TheWeeezel

Comment: I added the key and took away async defer... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Opening up dev tools and checking the console showed an error: `Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError`. There is also a provided link for a warning, also in this case related to a missing API key [`NoAPIKeys`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys).

Double check and make sure you have a Google Maps API key. If you don't have one, check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) and when you load the script, make sure you specify the API like in this example provided from the previous link: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Do you have an example you could make for me including all my code I listed where I would just have to switch with my API key? That would help a lot!

Comment: I did what you said but the console says INITMAP is not a function. Do you know how to fix this? @steph